# How to change KPH to MPH?

Tags: asphalt-8

How do you switch Asphalt 8: Airborne into MPH instead of KPH. I have a problem with metric stuff.

Answer (score 7):

go to the main screen and go to settings> sound and display> speed unit, and press MP/H

Answer (score 1):

### Go To

Settings>Sound And Display>Speed Unit

---

### Settings

[image: settings]

---

### Sound And Display

### [image: sound and display]

### Speed Unit

[image: speed unit]